# AppBarLayout refusing to do anything

Tags: android, material-design

I've tried several different articles, numerous threads here and tutorials but I cannot get this to do anything at all.

In my code, the Activity that uses this layout is a `AppCompatActivity`.
I have the `AppCompatTheme.Light.NoActionBar`

Inside my Activity I set `setSupportActionBar()` to the view `R.id.toolbar`.

This is my goal: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtkyx.gif

```
// Dependencies
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:21.0.3'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:6.1.0'
```

Here's my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/> 
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason you have two `Toolbar`s? Can you include the dependencies from your `build.gradle` file?

Comment: Added my dependencies.  I have two `Toolbar`s because I was just trying anything to get some results.

Comment: I removed the second toolbar from the xml to avoid any further confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use at least version 22.2.0 (currently [22.2.1](https://plus.google.com/u/0/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/XTtNCPviwpj)) of `RecyclerView` to take advantage of the design library functionality such as `AppBarLayout`:

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.1'
```

It was in 22.2.0 that they added support for nested scrolling, the underlying functionality that `AppBarLayout` relies on.

Answer (score -1):

Place the `Recyclerview` on top of the `AppBarLayout` like this
   `

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>


        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>


    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>



</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>`
```

And why use two `Toolbars`? Just wondering...

Comment: Changing the location of the RecyclerView makes no difference.